# If i want catch the value that i've pass in formal argument for fun1, how can i?

Tags: c, function, arguments

```
void fun1()
{
    puts("In fun1\n");
}
void fun2(void)
{
    puts("In fun2\n");
}
main()
{
    fun1();
    fun1(5);
    fun2();
}`
```

It is working properly but i want to catch the parameters value that i've pass, but in this format only.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I can comprehend what you mean by *"but in this format only."*
If you meant you don't have the liberty to change `void fun1()` to `void fun1(<some suitable data type>)`, then you can't achieve what you are trying to.

One of the most basic and common ways to pass arguments to `fun1()` is by changing

```
void fun1()
```

to

```
void fun1(int a)  //int for example
```

I have used `int` as the data type of the argument, it can be any of the following:

```
int
unsigned int
char
unsigned char
short
unsigned short
long
unsigned long
```

and so on..

There are many ways to use arguments to a function. You can possibly pick any basic standard reference book for C programming and see the chapter that deals with functions.

For a beginner, reading and more importantly understanding the C standard can be very hard, but its always the way going ahead. I'll provide you with the link to refer the C11 standard, which is the latest one.

Referring to [C11 standard, section 6.5.2.2 Function calls](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2),

> 2. If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that includes a prototype, the number of arguments shall agree with the number of parameters. Each argument shall have a type such that its value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of the type of its corresponding parameter.

and

> 4. An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument

Comment: "*The only way*" seems a bit misleading to me, cause actually, an empty argument list **does** mean arguments just aren't specified (as opposed to `void`, which clearly states "no arguments here"). The OP is using both, so might be confused here. Of course you are right, a function **definition** needs the arguments declared to actually pass them.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Yes, I agree. I am just finding it tough to explain the stuff in a language understandable to a beginner (no offence to OP). See the edit, I think that should cover it.

Comment: That's indeed a problem, if you have to start explaining the difference between a declaration and a definition ... :) I just sensed some confusion here, seeing one definition with `()` and another with `(void)` in OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

In short: You *can't*.

A little more detailed: A function prototype with just empty argument list means the function might be called with any number of arguments. You shouldn't use this to begin with, it's obsolete because it is unsafe practice, just declare a complete prototype with all arguments.

That said, *pre-standard* C had a mechanism to completely dynamically fetch arguments: [varargs.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/varargs.h.html). **DO NOT USE THIS**, it is nowadays replaced by [stdarg.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) which requires at least **one** declared argument.

Comment: It's not deprecated, but obsolete according to standard. But I think you extrapolate OP question, I don't think one sec that OP want use this feature. Or OP is just crazy XD

Comment: I'm too lazy to look it up right now, because it's not much of a semantical difference ... except you understand "obsolete" as "no longer available", which would be true for varargs.h, but not for empty argument lists in function declarations....

Comment: Upvote for stating the deprecation (and/or obsolescence). No C book states it that way.

Comment: @Stargateur that might be true. I got the idea seeing the explicit use of `(void)` in only **one** of the function definitions. There definitely seems to be **some** confusion here :)

Comment: For the sake of source, https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6p1. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Introductionp2, by definition is worst that deprecated ^^ they literally say, if you code a compiler don't implement this.

Comment: @Stargateur just wanted to say this is a mere question of the wording you choose. It means the same thing, at least in the context of IT systems and standards. But thinking about it, "obsolete" might be the better choice of a word anyways, so changing it here as well :)

Comment: @Stargateur it's a **language** feature, so compilers are still required to support it ;) maybe finally time to really **remove** crap that's already obsolete for 2 standard versions.